# Half-bridge circuit not working, high side running hot

Tags: mosfet, buck

As I'm a noob in this field I’m experimenting with a half bridge circuit to run a buck converter to learn about it. First I tested my circuit by putting everything together on a breadboard and it worked great. After soldering it together on a piece of perfboard I ran into a problem. When I apply a voltage to the circuit, the high side MOSFET runs very hot within seconds. I found that the high output of the gate driver doesn´t provide enough voltage to the gate, it outputs around 17V instead of 25V as it does on the breadboard (VCC is 15V). So I think something is wrong with my bootstrap circuit.

PWM is created by an ESP32 and SD is pulled to 5V.

[image: my schematic]

Things I tried so far:

- Doubled the bootstrap cap (ceramic) to 200 nF.
- Increased C4 from 100 nF to 10 uF (thought 100 nF might not be enough to charge the bootstrap cap).
- Tried several PWM frequencies from 20 to 75 kHz and duty cycles from 20 to 80%.
- Replaced the gate driver IC and MOSFETs.

Still the high side MOSFET is running hot.
Again, this design runs perfectly fine on the breadboard. I checked the connections on the perfboard more than once and it´s soldered together like in the schematic. I´m happy about any help!

Update: Here the VS and VB pins as requested in the comments, unfortunately I only have a potato China oscilloscope available. But I think what can be observed is that the V_min on the VB pin on the perfboard is way higher than on the breadboard. Can anyone observe what could be wrong with the circuit? Also note that the perfboard has a 1N5817W Schottky diode installed instead of the 1N4007 now.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! How does the VS and VB pins look on your scope? Have you tried a faster diode for D1?

Comment: Thank you! :) I didn´t try another diode yet, but also already thought about changing it. I just have a 1N5817W laying around, do you think that might be better? Or is it too weak? I can post a picture of VS and VB later on.

Comment: Check the trr time in ns for each bootstrap diode in the datasheet. You need a very fast one which can withstand Vcc+Vb+margin.

Comment: I'm thinking that 22uF cap may require a lot of current to charge up before your boost kicks in substantially.  Winny is right, look at VS and VB on the scope and post them.  What frequency are you running at?

Comment: You observed this:  I found that the high output of the gate driver doesn´t provide enough voltage to the gate, it outputs around 17V instead of 25V as it does on the breadboard (VCC is 15V). So I think something is wrong with my bootstrap circuit.     But in the list of things that you tried so far, checking the soldered circuit is missing. If it was working fine on the breadboard but not after you soldered, there is a chance that there are incorrect connections. Also, there is a possibility of  hear damage to the components, but lets assume that you soldered the components carefully for now.

Comment: Its tricky doing a pcb layout for high current switching circuits. Perfboard is not considered a good idea.

Comment: @winny, I added VB and VS as requested. Can you draw any conclusions from that? Adding the Schottky diode didn´t help unfortunately.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I tried running it at 75kHz, but also tried lower frequencies down to 20kHz. Still the same error appears.

Comment: @baschtlwaschtl What's the bandwidth on that potatoscope? It all looks bad, but some of it might be BW limitations of the potato.

Comment: Whoa! That doesn’t look even remotely correct. Any LP filter activated in the potato? It may in the end be down to that you need a real PCB, two layer minimum with good ground plane and proper decoupling to make it work.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about a real PCB as this just doesn't seem to work at all. I don't know if there is a LP filter active, but the bandwidth limit of the potato is definitely reached. Still it measured the different voltage levels compared to my breadboard version. Well then I'll probably spend Sunday designing a PCB...

Comment: I would once more check if everything is soldered ok, exchange components. Is impossible that it runs on the breadboard but no on the copper board. I tried a similar circuit recently and it has no problems running with mosfets on cables as long as 10cm. In Those bootstrap drivers one have to be really careful at the start, but when they once ran, they keep running :)

Comment: @fifi_22 I just checked everything again and also exchanged the High side MOSFET as well as the Driver IC. Nothing changed. It´s also already my second perfboard version of the circuit, as the first had also this issue. I assumed a coupling problem and therefore went for the second try with more space between the components. For now I will use the breadboard version then and later on design a PCB. 
Thank you all for your help, if anyone still has ideas I´m happy to try them out!

Comment: Show a photos of Your real circuit. Are You using the exact same mosfets as on the breadboard?

Comment: After some experimenting and some frustrating evenings I found the error which I would like to share so nobody else is doing that stupid mistake ever again.
Turned out my PWM signal was simply not Grounded and was floating around, resulting in the strange behaviour of the driver IC. Now it works like a charm.